# remove second question mark from query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I made a mistake in creating links. I corrected it but now still there are links floating around that might look like this:

http://www.domain.com/?page=1?date=29062015&id=778

I would like to correct this using the rewriteEngine to redirect my users to:

http://www.domain.com/?page=1&date=29062015&id=778

I searched around and tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^\/ ^\/$1\&$2 [L,R=301]
```

What should I change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly corrected your rule,hope it will help to resolve the issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Note that %1 and %2 are back-references to the matched part of the regular expression in the previous RewriteCond (Query string condition).

Good article about rewriting query string here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString